# Copying folder from usb drive to mac changes permission to 777

Tags: linux, macos, file-permissions, cp

I have different web projects that I need to move from one computer with Ubuntu to a Mac.
I'm using `cp -rp folder copy_folder` to copy from the hard disk to an external usb drive. After this operation the permission are still correct, but when I insert the usb drive in the Mac the permissions appears to be just 777.

Is there anything I can do to keep the same permission in the Mac?

Comment: What happens if you drop the `-p`? Perhaps your OS decides to put the permissions to 777 because the original uid does not map to a uid on your system.

Comment: no, the same happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of USB drives are formatted with a FAT32 file system and FAT32 file system does not support Unix permissions. However, permissions can be set at mount time.

If you want to keep the permissions on your file while transferring it from Linux to Mac, use another file system that can be read by both systems and that support Unix permissions such as ext4 (You'll need something like OSXFuse to do it).

A better and simpler solution would be to use rsync if both computer are connected to the same network or even the Internet.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was actually the pen drive and rsync did the trick